# How to get the Pairing PopUP in CORE Bluetooth class in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetoothlescanner

Not getting the pairing pop up when trying to connect to the device.[image: rin]

And value also is some random data which i am not able to read.

Comment: You should have the pairing pop-up when you try to read a characteristic which is protected (encrypted). Else, it's "open bar". For the value, what is it supposed to be? a String, a custom struct?

Comment: @Larme-If you can see the attached screenshot, on top characteristics i am getting the data of the value.I need to display the bytes data.But in Values parameter i am getting {""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""}

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xamarain, but in Swift, you need to "force" a read on the characteric value, and then it's not necessary a valid "String". Now, is the value "empty" (full double quotes) because you need a pairing first? If so, find a characteristic which is encrypted to pair (and it might reveal the value of this one).

Comment: @LarmeThanks for the answer but how can i get the encrypted characteristic

Comment: @Larme-After pairing also i am getting empty.But in CBCharacteristics i can see the data